# Using SAPI 5.1 under Win7 64

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition, sapi, phoneme

Im writing an automated Lip Syncing Tool that is based on the Annosoft Console Program ([Link to the Annosoft Tool](http://www.annosoft.com/sapi_lipsync/docs/)). This Program uses the SAPI 5.1. For me it works great on Win XP 32 Bit. But is there any way to get this to work under a Win7 64 Bit System?

P.S. the Console Program is open source, but im not very familiar with SAPI and audio processing, so rewriting the entire Code would not really be an option for me.

edit: I'm afraid my verbalisation wasn't really making my problem meaningful to others, so: Is it possible to get Windows SAPI 5.1 to work in Windows 7 64 bit? If yes - how?

Comment: SAPI 5.4 (comes default with Windows 7) is upwards compatible with SAPI 5.1.  What sort of problems are you having when you run the program directly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and I have it in my computer. Just install the SDK from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

If you don't want all the Windows SDK, take a look on here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

Cheers